# Chain an array of tasks in Concurrent Ruby

Tags: ruby, concurrency, promise, concurrent-ruby

I have a set of tasks that I want to execute sequentially in some background thread, with the result of each task being passed to the next, and with the chain failing if any link in the chain fails.

For the sake of argument, let's say each task is an object with an `exec` method that returns a value, although they could equally well be procs or lambdas.

What I have now is something like:

```
promise = array_of_tasks.inject(nil) do |promise, task|
            if promise
              promise.then { |prev_result| task.exec(prev_result) }
            else
              Concurrent::Promise.new { task.exec }
            end
          end

promise.on_success { |last_result| log.info("Success: #{last_result} ")}
promise.rescue { |reason| log.error("Failure: #{reason}")}
```

Is there a more concise way to do this, either in the `Promise` API or elsewhere in Concurrent Ruby? It seems like a fairly basic operation, but I'm not seeing an existing method that does it.

(Side note: if there isn't such a method, is there a well-known name for this pattern in the futures-and-promises world? I.e., if I write the method myself, is there some existing obvious name for it?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't shorter, but this structure might make it easier to add new functionality :

```
require 'concurrent'

class Task
  def exec(x = 0)
    sleep 0.1
    p x + 1
  end

  alias call exec

  def to_promise(*params)
    Concurrent::Promise.new { exec(*params) }
  end
end

module PromiseChains
  refine Concurrent::Promise do
    def chained_thens(callables)
      callables.inject(self) do |promise, callable|
        promise.then do |prev_result|
          callable.call(prev_result)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

It can be used this way :

```
using PromiseChains

array_of_tasks = Array.new(10) { Task.new } 

array_of_tasks << ->(x) { p x * 2 } 
array_of_tasks << proc { |x| p x * 3 }

first_task, *other_tasks = array_of_tasks

chain = first_task.to_promise.chained_thens(other_tasks)

chain.on_success { |last_result| puts "Success: #{last_result} " }
chain.rescue { |reason| puts "Failure: #{reason}" }

chain.execute
sleep(2)
```

It outputs :

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
20
60
Success: 60
```